# UML to XML representation

Tags: xml, eclipse, uml, papyrus

I build a class diagram using Eclipse modeling tool-Papyrus. how can i export UML diagram to XML format to see the class, attribute, and generalization, etc. relationships represented in XML? How can I do this?

Comment: If you want to export UML diagram to XML format you can use XML Spy's Schema Editor.

Comment: hello amitesh ,do you have other solution?i dont seek for editor

Comment: you can use microsoft visio if you want.. if that help you then let me know.

Comment: dear amitesh, i cant use microsoft visio because i intented to use MARTE so Papyrus support MARTE but microsoft visio not support MARTE

Comment: hi @safa Eng i search alot for this may be this link will help you http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/308606/  or try google search and sry for not helping you futher.

Comment: hello @amitesh thank you so much for your efforts

Comment: tell me link provided by me is helpful for you??? @safa Eng

Comment: hello @amitesh and thank you so much for help .yes your link shed some light on but there is still something like url and technical stuff information in xmi file of my diagram?i wonder whether or not this is the right way or there is an other?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have solved my question using Eclipse and posted the solution as series of steps

[image: step1]
[image: step2]
[image: step3]

Comment: What is the name of this software?

Answer (score 2):

According to the Papyrus website:

http://www.papyrusuml.org/scripts/home/publigen/content/templates/show.asp?P=130&L=EN&ITEMID=4

they do have: "Full respect of the DI2 (Diagram Interchange ) standard" see

http://www.omg.org/cgi-bin/doc?formal/2006-04-04.pdf

You'll find an example at:

- Diagram interchange: https://speedy.supelec.fr/Papyrus/svn/Papyrus/examples/UML2JAVA/HelloWorld/releases/1.0.0/HelloWorld/mdl/HelloWorld.di2
- XMI export: https://speedy.supelec.fr/Papyrus/svn/Papyrus/examples/UML2JAVA/HelloWorld/releases/1.0.0/HelloWorld/mdl/HelloWorld.uml

since I do not use Papyrus myself and the tutorials I browsed have no hint on how to actually do the export these are my two cents for a start ...

Comment: thank you @Wolfgang Fahl for your efforts but i am asking about how to convert UML to XML using Papyrus on condition every element of diagram represented in XML.because when i view the di in XML editor i only found it meaningless as it contains only technical stuff.Any other advice or suggestion?