# Generate XML file from UML Model in Java

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, uml

I want to make a java application that take `UML Model` and it's output is a `XML File`.

I want to know what is the library/API can i use in Java ? - and i want to know if there is any application that do this job ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13184412/uml-to-xml-representation

Comment: Standardized UML model is already XML file in the XMI format. What is it that you want/need to do? You know how to write code in `Java` and you have heard buzzwords `UML` and `XML` and the question is...?

Answer (score 1):

Most (if not all) UML tools will export to XMI, you can learn more at
[Wikipedia MOF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta-Object_Facility).  If you are really interested in code generation (rather than just parsing XML) there are eclipse related projects such as [eclipse emf](http://eclipse.org/modeling/emf/).  Good luck w/your journey.